# Grunt relative paths to base src for efficiency

Tags: gruntjs, relative-path

So, I've been working on optimizing my website. Right now, I have a very nice template going. It looks something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <!-- shiny optimizations -->
    ...
    <!-- Ooh look! An important example that will help you understand my question! -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "release/base/css/normalize.css">
    include "page/head.html"
</head>
<body>
    include = "page/body.html"
</body>
</html>
```

So in each page, it has a makeup of the following

- /release: a directory where minified, compressed files are put
- /source: a directory where the source files are

Now, I have a directory called /base (in the root) and it contains optimizations and other shiny stuff, like normalize, browser compatibility things, etc.

Base is going to stay the same in all projects, and so is the template file, but the locations of the projects will change. Take the following file structure for example.

```
base
    favicon.ico
    /css
        ...
    /js
        ...
source
    ...
release
    ...
foo
    /release
        ...
    /source
        ...
    index.html
    /foobar
        /release
            ...
        /source
            ...
        index.html
bar
    /release
        ...
    /source
        ...
    index.html
baz
    /release
        ...
    /source
        ...
    index.html
```

So baz, bar, and foo need to reference the optimizations through

```
../base
```

Foobar needs to reference it through

```
../../base
```

And root just needs to get it through

```
base
```

So based on how many files deep something is, I want to change it from

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{changeMeBasedOnFileDeepness}/base/css/normalize.css">
```

To

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../../../base/css/normalize.css">
```

tl;dr: I want to allow files to reference the base directory from wherever they are.

This is being done on github pages, you can view the repo [here](https://github.com/TheGenieOfTruth/thegenieoftruth.github.io/tree/master/sample)

Cheers,

TheGenieOfTruth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an XY problem. All I needed to do was get some shiny notation that looked like this:

`/base/css/...`

That was about to get painfully complex

So in short:

**When using a webserver, the `/foo/bar` notation will get you to the root directory**